# Generated type declarations convert implicit types to any

Tags: typescript, tsc, type-declaration

I am working on a module where I have to do something like this:

```
    const foo = () => {
        const bar = {
            a: () => bar,

            b: () => bar,

            c: () => bar
        }

        return bar
    }  

    foo().a().b().c()
```

Even though all types are implicit typescript is awesome and helps me autocomplete.

Since I have to publish to npm, I let tsc generate the types declarations, however this is what I get in the index.d.ts file:

```
declare const foo: () => {
    a: () => any;
    b: () => any;
    c: () => any;
};
```

Which means that whoever install my module will not be able to take full advantage of typescript goodness.

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give TS compiler a small tip to help figure out the types:

```js
interface Bar {
  a: () => Bar;
  b: () => Bar;
  c: () => Bar;
}

const foo = () => {
  const bar: Bar = {
    a: () => bar,
    b: () => bar,
    c: () => bar
  }

  return bar
}

const result = foo().a() // Bar
```

**Second option** - recursion approach

```js
type Rec<Bar> = Record<keyof Bar, () => Rec<Bar>>

const foo = () => {

  const bar = {
    a: () => bar,
    b: () => bar,
    c: () => bar
  } as const
  type Bar = typeof bar;
  return bar as Rec<Bar>
}

const result = foo().a().b().b().c(); // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", ...>>
```

TS compiler puts `any` here:

```js
declare const result: Readonly<Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Readonly<Record<"a" | "b" | "c", any>>>>;
```

because it is a recursion type. What would you expect to see here?

```js
declare const result: Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c",  () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c",any>>>>>>>;
// ... Infinity
```

TS should stop somewhere)

Comment: I see that this will work, however it is a bit of a problem for me because I don't just have a, b and c, instead I have about 30 functions with different input signatures, and this pattern is repeated in several files. In addition, every time I modify a function I would also have to update the interface, which seems to violate DRY.

Comment: The second option is interesting, however, the generated index.d.ts file looks like this: declare type Rec<Bar> = Record<keyof Bar, () => Rec<Bar>>;
declare const foo: () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", () => Record<"a" | "b" | "c", any>>;                    The any at the end results in the original problem

Comment: @Sarrio it is true, there is `any`, but you will never end up with `any`

Comment: @Sarrio I suppose, you can't move `bar` out of the scope of `foo`, correct?

Comment: Actually ```any``` is problematic: I just tried publishing it to npm and installing the package into another module, and as expected if I do ```const test = foo().a()```  then ```test``` is of type ```any``` and I cannot use autocomplete anymore. However, If I do the same thing inside the original package then it works, I guess this is because typescript directly interprets the original .ts file and understands the recursion, but when imported into another package it will just look for the .d.ts file which contains that ```any``` that breaks the autocompletion.

Comment: yes I cannot move bar outside of the scope of foo because foo is a constructor, in reality bar will old some additional information that is unique for every instance

Comment: So, foo is a class?

Comment: Nope, foo is just a function which has the same role that constructors have in Classes, and bar is the objected constructed by foo. I didn't use Classes for performance reasons. After a few tests with console.time() I realized that for my use case Classes were 4-6 times slower than just simple JSON objects. If you want more context just take a look at my repo https://github.com/ChristianMarchetta/tv  It's a validator similar to joi that automatically converts schemas to types so that you don't need to declare types identical to schemas. Didn't have time to properly document it though.